# Java ServerSocket won't send or receive messages from client

Tags: java, sockets, server, client-server, serversocket

I have these two classes *Client.java* and *Server.java*, each containing a `main` method. The idea is very simple and the code in them is very similar. The objective I'm trying to achieve is opening a *server* that listens on a specific port using `ServerSocket`, then open a *client* and connect to the server using `Socket` so that I can finally send messages from *client* to *server* and reverse until I close the connection.

So far, I tried the easiest example, opened *server* on **port** 4444, then on the **same** PC I've opened a client to connect to the **address** 127.0.0.1 (localhost), on **port** 4444. Everything runs smooth, the connection is established successfully every time, excepting it won't send any message, either from server to client or client to server.

**The final question is, what should I do to be able to exchange messages between server and client? What should I modify?**

### Client.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    private static Socket client;
    private static BufferedReader in, console;
    private static PrintWriter out;

    private static String serverAddress;
    private static int port;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.print("Connect to server address (example 192.168.10.11): ");
            serverAddress = console.readLine();

            System.out.print("Port: ");
            port = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());

            System.out.println("\nTrying to connect...");
            client = new Socket(serverAddress, port);

            System.out.println("Connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());

            out.write("Connected!!!!!!");

            Thread input = new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    String tmp;

                    try {
                        while((tmp = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println("Server: " + tmp);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread output = new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    String tmp;

                    try {
                        while((tmp = console.readLine()) != null) {
                            out.print(tmp);
                        }
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };


            input.start();
            output.start();

            while(true) {
                if(!input.isAlive() && !output.isAlive()) {
                    client.close();

                    in.close();
                    console.close();
                    out.close();

                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {   
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

### Server.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket server;
    private static BufferedReader in, console;
    private static PrintWriter out;

    private static int port;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.print("Open server on port (example 1234): ");
            port = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());

            System.out.println("Server open");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            System.out.println("Waiting for a client to connect...\n");
            server = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("Client " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " connected!");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);

            Thread input = new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    String tmp;

                    try {
                        while((tmp = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println("Client: " + tmp);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread output = new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    String tmp;

                    try {
                        while((tmp = console.readLine()) != null) {
                            out.print(tmp);
                        }
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            input.start();
            output.start();

            while(true) {
                if(!input.isAlive() && !output.isAlive()) {
                    serverSocket.close();
                    server.close();

                    in.close();
                    console.close();
                    out.close();

                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Here is a tutorial that looks alot like your code. It does what you are asking for. http://www.careerbless.com/samplecodes/java/beginners/socket/SocketBasic1.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already viewed many tutorials like this one. The problem is I am trying to use those 2 threads in both classes, just so input and output from server to client and reverse work simultaneously, just like any classic live chat. I managed to make it work without the threads, so most probably the problem is inside the run() methods. @Remixt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading lines but you aren't wring lines. Instead of `out.write()` and `out.print()` you should use `out.println()`.

Comment: Also you have to flush the stream in this case `out.flush()` on each message that you want to send or `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);` on the client class as you have on the server class.

Comment: Thank you EJP for the answer, using println and flushing made it work finally. In order to mark your answer, can you please explain how using println instead of print made it work? @EJP

Comment: I've already explained. In my answer. You weren't writing lines. `println()` writes lines. See the Javadoc.

Comment: @HectorVenturaReyes No he doesn't The `true` parameter in the constructor you cited makes that automatic.

Comment: @AndreiMeși you have to options to send the data to the connected socket, first is to set to `true` the second parameter on the PrintWriter constructor or execute a flush after the println method.

@AndreiMeși good luck.

Comment: @HectorVenturaReyes If that's meant to be an answer you should have posted it as such, but the issue here is not the flushing,it is the lack of a line terminator.